# How do I format 1 to many relation in a CSV file

Tags: java, csv

I have a data set I need to format into a csv file so I can import it into a database. The data is large and manually inputting the data is not an option. I'm currently creating a program in java for it.

The data setup is as follows:
1 User (userID) is part of many Groups (groupID)

However I'm not sure how I can present this in a CSV file, as there's only 1 character separator.

Will I have to keep printing out the same user for each group it's tied to in the CSV file, like so:

```
userID|groupID
1|group1
1|group2
1|group3
1|group4
1|group5
2|group1
2|group4
```

then run a query in the database?

Comment: I would do this in separate flat files or use something like [json](http://json.org).

Comment: i guess that is what you use excel for but be more specific as to what you want to do as your question apart from the excel thing is not clear

Comment: We intend to import it into a mysql database and query the database for our research report

Comment: i guess then you can use the option suggested by Gabriel below. you would store the group in a Varchar() column as a Stringin the db. So you can query based on userId and fetch the groups. i guess there should not be any problem doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest putting a comma-separated list of groups between quotation marks, like the following:

```
userID|groups 
1|"group1,group2,group3"
2|"group1,group3"
3|"group5"
```

You can use any other separator for the groups column but the idea is to enclose the list in quotation marks

Comment: I doubt it will recognize this format automatically as a one-to-many relationship. You have to programatically interpret the "groups" column when reading the file and add it appropriately to the database. So, for one row in the CSV file, you would create one row for a user and x rows for the groups, where x is the number of comma-delimited groups in the last column

Comment: Are the quotations with commas inside a standard for a csv list grouping or can other characters be used? Will I need to select a grouping character when I import the csv file?

Comment: Thanks I'll have a play around with it.

Comment: CSV files have always been used with a lot of flexibility. There's little to classify as "standard". If the quotations with commas inside works for you, there's nothing to stop you from using it. I've used this format myself

Comment: If consider the answer to bo good don't forget to mark it as correct please :)

Comment: Is there a tutorial I could follow online to import this into a mysql database? I'm not really a database guy..

Comment: I found this one to be particularly relevant -> http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-load-csv-file-to-database/  Remember, for each row in the CSV, you add a row in the user table, and x rows in the groups table, where x is the number of groups

Comment: If you need, I can help you out with some code, but I will only be available to do that in about 5-6hrs

Comment: All good, just skimmed over it quickly. I see what you mean now by programmatically interpreting the groups, I just didn't realise you were talking about doing it in java. When I said I was making a java program, I meant I was gathering data with a java program. Sorry. Will now check out how to setup a database through java lol..

Comment: Hi Gabriel. It's a bit hard to read the code in the link you posted above with all the regular expressions the author has put into it. Will this example suffice for what I need to do? http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/

Comment: It is sufficient for inserting into the database. If you havent found one already, you also need a library for reading the csv file. Try OpenCSV